# How to include all templates into one angular file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, gruntjs

I am developing an angular module, this module is integrated for several sources files, js for controllers, directives and services and html for templates what I use in directives, this would be my dev enviroment, and I use grunt for compiles all sources files, but I don't know how handle the templates to compile in the same file. What are the best options for doing this? I saw angular-bootstrap does that, but I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Grunt, you can use [grunt-html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js). This ng-learn post explains in detail how to do it: http://ng-learn.org/2014/08/Populating_template_cache_with_html2js/

HTML2JS is quite powerful by itself - for instance, you can use it to load directive templates in your tests as well.